# Alternative GUI for Open Source Job Scheduler?

Tags: job-scheduling

Are there some alternative open source GUI developed to improve the management of jobs and job chains in [Open Source Job Scheduler](http://jobscheduler.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 3+ months I didn't receive any answer, so I guess is time to answer myself "No. Seems like there aren't any alternative open source GUI developed for Job Scheduler".

Answer (score 2):

I know this is tooooo old to answer. But **yes**, a graphical XML editor for job configuration and a web GUI for job management are available. JobScheduler can be controlled by the built-in web server's graphical user interface. JobScheduler uses an XML file for the configuration of executable files or shell scripts and to set the timing and frequency of job starts.

**JobScheduler has two web based GUIs:**

**• Operations GUI**

To operate the operations GUI the no web server is needed, because JobScheduler has its own built-in web server.

**• Managed Jobs GUI**

To operate the Managed Jobs interface at least an Apache or IIS is required. In addition, the Managed Jobs web interface needs PHP.

Read more [here](http://www.sos-berlin.com/modules/cjaycontent/index.php?id=79&page=osource_scheduler_faq_en.htm#question_51)

Answer (score 0):

Update 2018

[Chronos](https://mesos.github.io/chronos/) is a Job scheduler. It run on top of Apache Mesos, so it's a best to install if you are not running a data center, but it gets the job done. Comes with a GUI as well. Stores job state in Zookeeper.